# Prev and Next buttons in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to go from page 1 to page 4, in Angular 4, with a prev and next button.
Each page, from 1 to 4, is a individual component.

My buttons component is on the bottom on each page.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
 <div class="trade-75"><button type="button" class="btn trade-back">

 </button></div>
 <div class="trade-10"><button type="button" class="btn trade-next">

 </button></div>
</div>
```

I was thinking to put in an array all components and to loop thought this array, but I don't know how to do this in Angular 4 :). Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something simple like this

```
<div class="page">
    <my-first-page *ngIf="currentPage == 0"></my-first-page>
    <my-second-page *ngIf="currentPage == 1"></my-second-page>
    <my-third-page *ngIf="currentPage == 2"></my-third-page>
    <my-fourth-page *ngIf="currentPage == 3"></my-fourth-page>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="trade-75">
        <button type="button" class="btn trade-back" (click)="changePage(-1)"></button>
    </div>
     <div class="trade-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn trade-next" (click)="changePage(1)"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in a component

```
export class WizardComponent {
    public currentPage = 0;
    public changePage(delta: number): void {
        // some checks
        currentPage += delta;
    }
}
```

Comment: You approach is nice, but the app will grow up so I will have more than 4 components and then this will be hard to modify

Comment: @JohnSmith I see your point. Maybe you'll find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/504075